# oracle sql - update unless update will duplicate on unique

Tags: sql, sql-update, duplicates, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm working with a users table and changing a userName field to  userName||'test'  Unfortunately, somewhere along the way, there are already converted userNames that are equal to this already.  As userName has a unique constraint, I need a way to update these fields unless they would result in a duplicate.  I've been looking everywhere online for help on it and so far only found a generic "make your update not cause duplicates" without more on how to do that with oracle.

Table:
Primary  varchar  unique varchar
user_id   name      userName

Need to update all userNames to userName = userName || 'test' unless userName||'test' already exists.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What would you do if `userName||'test'` already exists - use a different pattern, or leave that `userName` as it was? Have you looked at the `not exists` test?

Comment: If userName||'test' already exists, it should change it to userName||'duplicate' so I can go back through and manually check before cleanup.

Comment: If you're going to clean up manually anyway then you might as well use guildbounty's answer; then after running, look for any where `username not like '%test'` rather than `like '%duplicate'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that userName is currently distinct, and there are not pre-existing duplicates to deal with...

```
UPDATE UserTable ut1
SET userName = userName || 'test'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM UserTable ut2
    WHERE ut2.userName LIKE ut1.userName || 'test'
)
```

I will add a cautionary statement about the NOT EXISTS clause. It can very rapidly spiral into horrible performance territory. It is useful, but should be used with caution.

Comment: I gave this a try and it still resulted in the ORA-00001 unique constraint error.  I used..
UPDATE users
  SET userName = userName ||'test'
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM users u2
    WHERE userName LIKE userName || 'test'
    )
    AND userName NOT LIKE '%test';

Comment: Is the userName the primary key? I can't really decipher the Table description you have up there. If so, I can think of two possible options that might be still causing you trouble.

Comment: user_id is the primary key.  Sorry, still new to stack's formatting.  Apparently a hard enter doesn't equal a line break.

Comment: Okay, does userName have a unique constraint attached to it? I'm assuming yes, but that isn't visible in your table definition

Comment: Only that it must be unique, as far as I'm aware.  Ie:  if bob and bobtest exist, bob cannot become bobtest and should be skipped or changed to bobduplicate, etc.

Comment: I made a small update to my answer, I realized I forgot the aliases on the tables...try it again with the aliases in place.

Comment: That was the last missing piece!  Thank you so much.